# SQL type IGNORE_DUP_KEY

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE ([Id] [int] NULL)
GO
```

How can I insert the same value multiple times in a type?

Guess it is something like `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`, but I can't seem to get to work

Comment: If there is no key or index on the column (as there isn't, in the statement you've given) then there already is no restriction on inserting the same value multiple times in a table. `DECLARE @i IdList; INSERT @i VALUES (1), (1), (1)` will work just fine.

Comment: @Larnu: `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` is exactly the option you use to tell SQL Server to ignore the duplicate (as in, discard inserts rather than producing an error). I'm not a fan, but it *is* there. `CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE ([Id] [int] NULL, INDEX IX_IdList_ID UNIQUE(ID) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON))` will create a table type that ignores attempts to insert duplicates. That may actually be what the OP wanted, though that wasn't the question as I read it...

Comment: Thanks working now

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you should provide an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no key or index on the column (as there isn't, in the statement you've given) then there already is no restriction on inserting the same value multiple times in a table.

```
DECLARE @i IdList
INSERT @i VALUES (1), (1), (1)
```

will work just fine. If you want to have a unique index with the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option so inserts will be discarded if the value is already there, rather than producing a constraint violation, you can do so by including a unique index with that option in the declaration:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE (
    [Id] [int] NULL, 
    INDEX IX_IdList_Id UNIQUE(ID) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
);
```

Or with a primary key (for non-nullable columns):

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE ([Id] [int] PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON));
```

Be careful with this, because silently discarding duplicate values can be a real good way to mask essential problems in your processing. SQL Server does produce the informational message "Duplicate key was ignored", but that message is itself easy to ignore (and gives no details on what key(s)).

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen Mostert did tell me just to remove the key and i did ant did work